# skeleton app for swing

Tags: java, swing

I'm starting a simple project in swing but i don't want to start from scratch i'm searching a basic starting point with toolbars, file menu and basic functionality that works (exit from the application, button toolbar with a simple actionListener ...). I know there are eclipse rcp and the netbeans one but they are too big for my project. I'm searching something similar to the [jgoodies skeleton](http://www.jgoodies.com/freeware/skeleton/index.html) but it has to be opensource.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure it's exactly what you want, but the [Swing Application Framework](https://appframework.dev.java.net/) project might be worth a look.  It's "a small set of Java classes that simplify building desktop applications" rather than a "skeleton".

I haven't used it myself, so I couldn't vouch for it's usefulness.